# How to check contents of message without including User's name in contents

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Ive got a command im testing that enables the Bot to send me a message when a specific string is passed into a Channel.

My command works fine, but the bot seems to also include the user's name into the contents as well.

I found this out by testing with my name as the string the bot is running an if statement for, and found out that even typing just Hi, or any other message triggers the if statement as my name 'Jerseyetr" is included in the contents of the message.

```
if (message.content.includes('jersey') || ('jerseyetr')) {
            try{
                console.log('it worked!');
                //jersey.send('testing!');
                //client.users.get("xxxxxx").send("test");
                return;
                //guild.member
            }
                catch (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log('it did NOT work. Sad face');
                }
}
```

What would be the proper way to filter out the User's name?

Comment: What is the response while calling the GET route could you update that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you **always** enter in the if, and never in the else (if there's one).

Why? Because of your condition. The OR condition `||` will test first the `message.content.includes('jersey')`. If it's `true` it will enter in the if, if it's false it will test the second condition. But your second condition is always true, because the string `'jerseyetr'` is not empty and is considered true by Javascritps.
[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) list all the things that are considered *falsy*. All the other value are considered `true`.

I guess you wanted to do this:

```js
if (message.content.includes('jersey') || message.content.includes('jerseyetr')) {
  ...
}
```

However, the second expression isn't needed because `jersey` is contained in `jerseyetr`, so if the message contains `jerseyetr`, it will also contains `jersey`.

You'll see that Discord doesn't includes the username in the `message.content` but only the text of the message

*Side note*: if you want to test something like this in your message, you can maybe use a regexp:

```js
/jersey/.test(message.content)
```

Comment: There's actually no need for the second expression; `jerseyetr` itself contains `jersey`, so the first expression would evaluate to `true` anyway.

Comment: @slothiful if the message contains jersey, yes you're right. I'll add a note about this, good point

Comment: Thank you, I had made an oversight out of sheer lack of energy. Thanks for pointing out the fix.